# Why equal sign was used for limit outside of external conductor?

Tags: electromagnetism

Why limit is r >= b when magnetic induction is zero instead of r > b?
Example: An air coaxial line made of copper (μ ~ μ0) is given. A constant current I flows through the inner conductor. The radius of the inner conductor is a and the outer conductor is of negligible thickness of radius b.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you asking why there is no magnetic flux outside the outer dimension?

Comment: I am asking why limit outside of outer conductor is r >= b instead of r > b?

Comment: There has to be some account of flux density at "b" and in-between "a" and "b" the limits don't cover "b" exactly. I'd be more concerned that the "a" limit is doubly specified at the boundary of "a". That's a more glaring error.

Comment: In an ideal conductor, currents induced on the surface cancel the magnetic field at that point.  Presumably the author of this example interpreted the radius b to be the beginning of the conductor rather than the end of the air.  IRL it makes no difference, your conductors won't usually be ideal, and the question of whether the conductor starts at b or b+epsilon is moot, or at least within tolerance.

Comment: Equal sign was used in both r <= a and a <= r < b because when a is replaced with r in both equations they will be same Andy aka

Comment: Why is a <= r < b and r >= b instead of a <= r <= b and r > b?